# display two columns from a datatable in combobox

Tags: c#, database, winforms, combobox, datatable

> I want to concatenate the name and surname from the table "person" into the combobox1.
>   any solutions please !

```
   public MyForm()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        combobox1_load();
        }

   public void combobox1_load()
    {
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from PERSONNE ", cn);
        dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            cn.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "NOM_PERSONNE , PRENOM_PERSONNE";
           // comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID_PERSONNE";
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }


    }
```

I tried to change the sqldataadapter like that -> 
da = new SqlDataAdapter(""select concat(NOM_PERSONNE,' ',PRENOM_PERSONNE) from PERSONNE",cn); ..
but it's not working too !!

Comment: Your way to concatenate fields together is the right one, but you should give a name to the resulting concatenation and use that name in the DisplayMember property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESOLVED !!

```
   public void combobox1_load()
    {
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select concat(NOM_PERSONNE,' ',PRENOM_PERSONNE) as 'nom_prenom' from PERSONNE ", cn);
        dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            cn.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "nom_prenom";
          //   comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID_PERSONNE";
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

the SQL query should be like this:"select concat(NOM_PERSONNE,' ',PRENOM_PERSONNE) AS PERSONNEName  from PERSONNE
and the display member should be :
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "PERSONNEName";

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("select NOM_PERSONNE,PRENOM_PERSONNE from PERSONNE ", cn);
```

instead of

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from PERSONNE ", cn);
```

and

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "NOM_PERSONNE" + "PRENOM_PERSONNE";
```

insted of

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "nom_prenom";
```

Comment: I tried but all items of the combobox are like that -> System.Data.DataRowView